# Dimensions of the instanton moduli space from Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, quantum-field-theory

Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer [Ref 1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/79638?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) states that the number of 
**virtual dimensions** of the instanton moduli space
for SU(N) Yang-Mills theory with topological charge $\mathcal{Q}$ over a manifold $X$ is given by
$$
D=4N \mathcal{Q} - (N^2-1)\frac{\chi(X) + \sigma(X)}{2} \;,
$$
where $\chi$ and $\sigma$ are the Euler number and the signature of the 4-manifold $X$.

> Questions:

1. If I understand correctly, the **virtual dimensions** coincide with the actual **dimensions for irreducible solutions** when the gauge group is completely broken by the solutions. What is the mathematical definition of *virtual dimension*, precisely, of the instanton moduli space?
2. If I understand correctly, $\mathcal{Q}$ shall be related to the Pontryagin class $p_1(E)$? (in p.428 or in p.431)
   $$
   \mathcal{Q} \sim  p_1(E) = -\frac{1}{ 4 \pi^2}\int \text{tr}(\Omega^2)=
   \frac{1}{ 4 \pi^2}\int |\Omega|^2 \omega,
   $$
   where $\Omega$ is the curvature 2-form and $\omega$ is the volume form?
3. How to digest this dimension equality $
   D=4N \mathcal{Q} - (N^2-1)\frac{\chi(X) + \sigma(X)}{2}$?

Since $D$ is a dimension, $D$ is an integer.

(1) Can $D=0$?

(2) $\chi(X) + \sigma(X)$ must be an even integer, for the $D$ to be an integer.

(3) Since $D \geq 0$, and the integer $D \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$4N \mathcal{Q} > (N^2-1)\frac{\chi(X) + \sigma(X)}{2}$$
always. Why is this true intuitively? How do we see that increasing the $\frac{\chi(X) + \sigma(X)}{2}$, we obtain a smaller $D$?

[Ref 1: M. F. Atiyah, N. J. Hitchin, and I. M. Singer, Selfduality in Four-Dimensional Riemannian Geometry, Proc. Roy. Soc. Lond. A362 (1978) 425–461.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/79638?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: The virtual dimension is a Fredholm index of some elliptic complex. And a very small computation shows why $\chi+\sigma$ is even (see for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599833/compact-oriented-4k-manifold-euler-characteristic-is-congruent-to-the-signat). Your questions will be generally answered when reading introductory notes on this stuff (see for example: Kronheimer-Donaldon's book *"The geometry of four-manifolds"*).

Comment: The claim that this coincides with the "actual dimension" of the space of solutions is only true under transversality conditions which do not necessarily hold. This is true on a simply connected manifold for generic choice of metric. There is no reason to believe that $D \geq 0$. You can make $\chi + \sigma$ an arbitrarily large number, say by connect summing copies of $\Bbb{CP}^2$. I don't think there's a reason to think that there should be intuitive content to an index theory calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful guidelines. Thanks!